# Insert Values of Vector into Data Frame on Nearest Value

Tags: r, dataframe

```
a <- c(1,45,90,115,170,203,259)
b <- c(35,60,110,145,190,231,270)
df <- data.frame(a,b)

c <- c(27,175, 230)
```

I would like to insert the values of `c` into `df` and the row position of the values should depend on where they fall between the values of column `a` and `b`. E.g. `c[2]` (175) should appear on the same row as a = 170 & b = 190, 230 should go on the same row as a = 203 b = 270, etc.

`c` contains less values than `df` -- so cells are fine to be `NA`.

I can't find an answer to this anywhere. The best I've found is the `roll = nearest` feature in data tables, but this won't allow a 'not larger' condition.

I could use a for loop, however the data is big so that would be a resoursive method.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: please provide an example of your desired output.

Comment: The desired dataframe columns will appear as:                                                     a: 1, 45, 90, 115, 170, 203, 259                                                                         b: 35, 60, 110, 145, 190, 231, 270.                                                                   c: 27, NA, NA, NA, 175, 230, NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `findInterval()` to identify valid indexes

```
aidx = findInterval(c, df$a)
bidx = findInterval(c, df$b) + 1
keep = aidx == bidx
```

then update the original data frame

```
df[aidx[keep], "c"] = c[keep]
```

I would expect this to be fast for up to 100's of millions of rows, provided the data.frame rows are already sorted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be fast, you can try the `non-equi` join feature of `data.table` version `1.9.7`:

```
library(data.table)
v <- c(27, 175, 230)
v_dt <- data.table(id = v, c = v)  # create a data table with an identical column to 
                                   # join with df

v_dt[setDT(df), .(a, b, c), on = .(id > a, id < b), allow = T]

#     a   b   c
#1:   1  35  27
#2:  45  60  NA
#3:  90 110  NA
#4: 115 145  NA
#5: 170 190 175
#6: 203 231 230
#7: 259 270  NA
```

If you don't have `data.table` `1.9.7`, you can use `foverlaps`. The default `type` parameter is `any` which means as long as the value in `[id, c]` from `v_dt` has any overlap with range `[a, b]` from `df`, they will match, since `id == c` for each row, this is equivalent to `id` falls within the range:

```
setkey(v_dt, id, c)
setkey(df, a, b)

foverlaps(df, v_dt)[, id := NULL][,.(a, b, c)]

#     a   b   c
#1:   1  35  27
#2:  45  60  NA
#3:  90 110  NA
#4: 115 145  NA
#5: 170 190 175
#6: 203 231 230
#7: 259 270  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using base R.

```
#sample data
a <- c(1,45,90,115,170,203,259)
b <- c(35,60,110,145,190,231,270)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
c <- c(27,175, 230)

#Solution
#create place holder column
df$c<-NA
#find rows where the elements of c will fit
location<-which(c > df$a & c<df$b)
#update dataframe
df$c[location]<-c
```

The which command will throw a bunch of warnings but that should not matter.  This solution will only work if there is 1 and only solution for each element in the vector c.